# Case statement not seeing value

Tags: sql-server

No novice here but also no expert. I have the following example:

```
Declare @Test VARCHAR(max) = 'Value1, Value2'
select case when 'Value1' in (@Test) then 1 else 0 end as Col1
```

returns 0, shouldn't I expect it to return 1?  I need it to return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `LIKE` operator to find out, if your search string is contained or not.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @Test like '%Value1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COL1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works.  Been making reports all day and just wasn't seeing it like this.  Thanks again.

Comment: You also may want to use the `iif`-function substituting the `CASE` as it is not that bulky: `iif(@Test LIKE '%Value1%, 1, 0)`

Comment: @mrbungle pls consider accepting one of the answers providing an appropriate solution

Answer (score 3):

First lets look at what your code does. It's equivalent to saying "if the string literal 'a' is in the set of objects containing the string literal 'b', return 1 else 0"

Replace 'a' with 'Value1' and 'b' with 'Value1, Value2' and you'll see the statements are equivalent. There are two ways you can get at what you want. First, you could change your query to a wildcard search.

```
select case when @test like '%Value1%' then 1 else 0 end
```

The second is a bit more complicated, but hold truer to the idea of a relational database. First, you would need to split the test string into a table containing the values 'value1' and 'value2'. At this point, since they're distinct values, and not a single string literal, you can then do an IN lookup. Assuming you have a string split function called dbo.stringSplit

```
select case when 'Value1' in (select stringValue from dbo.stringSplit(@Test, ',')) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: If i was using this as a SP I would just use out split function but this is being used in ssrs report and the sql text is being used instead of SP, however thanks for the first suggestion.  upvoted along with the post answering the same.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `@Test` is a single string. You may want to split its value to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Value1' in ('Value1', 'Value2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COL1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately I need it to evaluate the parameter.